# Jenkins safely aborting child process

Tags: python, jenkins, hpcc

I have a Jenkins job that starts a python program on a cluster via SSH from a windows slave.
The program has a cleanup step that is triggered via a python finally statement for any kind of exception.
I would like to have this cleanup step run when the job is aborted via Jenkins web interface but Jenkins seems to forcibly terminate this process not letting it run the finally statement.
According to https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build
the process is terminated via the TerminateProcess API in windows.

Is there any way to get Jenkins to simply interrupt a child process and wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this can be adding the clean-up step as part of "POST BUILD ACTION (execute shell)".

When you abort a build (e.g. click the x mark once), Jenkins will still run the post-build actions. 
Jenkins will abort the post-build-action if you try to forcibly terminate the process (click 'x' mark more than once)

For this, you might need to modify/split your scripts

Comment: Yes that is one way to do it. However it would be very troublesome to split the scripts in this case. I am also running this program without using Jenkins, so I don't want to to modify it specifically for Jenkins.